# Angularjs UI-GRID dynamic cell template for each cell

Tags: angular-ui-grid, celltemplate

I have a UIGrid with 3 columns. Based on the value of 2nd column, I need to create custom cell template for 3rd column. Example :

Row 1 : Expression1 : String : TextBox

Row 2 : Expression2 : Boolean : Dropdown with true & false.

I have tried adding custom cell template to the 3rd Column like snippet below:-

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        { name: 'expression', displayName: 'Expression',enableCellEdit: false,enableSorting: false, width: '40%'},
        { name: 'type', displayName: 'Type',enableCellEdit: false,enableSorting: false, width: '30%' },
        { name: 'value', displayName: 'Value',enableCellEdit:true,enableSorting: false, width: '30%',editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
            editDropdownOptionsArray: [
                                       { id: 1, value: 'true' }, 
                                       { id: 2, value: 'false' }
        }
      ];
```

But in this case the 3rd column cell will always have a dropdown with true and false. I need dynamic cell template based on the value of 2nd column cell, the 3rd column cell type has to be TextBox or Dropdown. Is there a way I can do this???

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker?